# Decrypting ZigBee paquets

Tags: encryption, aes, zigbee, 802.11p

I would like to decrypt Zigbee paquets from a [Xiaomi Aqara switch](https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32969829478.html?src=google&albch=shopping&acnt=248-630-5778&isdl=y&slnk=&plac=&mtctp=&albbt=Google_7_shopping&aff_platform=google&aff_short_key=UneMJZVf&&albagn=888888&isSmbAutoCall=false&needSmbHouyi=false&albcp=10191220517&albag=107473525088&trgt=743612850874&crea=fr32969829478&netw=u&device=c&albpg=743612850874&albpd=fr32969829478&gclid=Cj0KCQiAyJOBBhDCARIsAJG2h5eZDuMg0qn8PxRNhYsKlsE1dw0pJmKJKqwAYCzjzE3PfEtr_ApziioaAlNzEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds). Here is the raw encrypted frame I sniffed on a network:

**Raw encrypted frame**

```
61 88 64 47 24 00 00 8A 5C 48 02 00 00 8A 5C 1E 5D 28 E1 00 00 00 01 3C E8 01 00 8D 15 00 01 00 01 12 00 04 01 01 62 18 C3 0A 55 00 21 01 00 AC 4C 76 AF 8A FB
```

Here is the same decrypted frame (decrypted with [Ubiqua](https://www.ubilogix.com/ubiqua/)):

**Decrypted frame**

```
61 88 64 47 24 00 00 8A 5C 48 02 00 00 8A 5C 1E 5D 28 E1 00 00 00 01 3C E8 01 00 8D 15 00 01 EA 59 DE 1F 96 0E EA 8A EE 18 5A 11 89 30 96 41 4E 05 A2 43 8A FB
```

Here is the same frame detailed:

```
MAC Header :    61 88 64 47 24 00 00 8A 5C
MAC Payload:    48 02 00 00 8A 5C 1E 5D
NWK Aux Header: 28 E1 00 00 00 01 3C E8 01 00 8D 15 00 01
NWK Payload:    00 01 12 00 04 01 01 62 
APS Payload:    18 C3 0A 55 00 21 01 00 
NWK MIC:        AC 4C 76 AF 
MAC Footer:     8A FB
```

I also know the ZigBee network key:

```
AD:8E:BB:C4:F9:6A:E7:00:05:06:D3:FC:D1:62:7F:B8
```

I would like to write a code for decrypting the paquets, but I can't figure out how to do this. I know the algorithm used is EAS-128, I try online tools like [cryptii](https://cryptii.com/pipes/aes-encryption), but I can't output the decrypted frame presented above.

I also do not know which version should be used (CBC, CFB, OFB, CTR, GCM, ECB) neither what is the initialization vector IV.

Any explaination, working solution with online tools, or code written in Python, node.js, PHP or C/C++ is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm is AES-128-CCM*, detailed in the [section 4.3.1.1](https://lucidar.me/en/zigbee/files/docs-05-3474-21-0csg-zigbee-specification.pdf#page=404&zoom=100,93,0) and [annex A of the ZigBee specification](https://lucidar.me/en/zigbee/files/docs-05-3474-21-0csg-zigbee-specification.pdf#page=479&zoom=100,93,0).

Detailed answer with the frame in the question: https://lucidar.me/en/zigbee/zigbee-frame-encryption-with-aes-128-ccm/